# How to use ROW() in an Excel VLOOKUP formula?

Tags: excel-formula

I have two formulas for a cell reference: `="D"&ROW()` and `="D$"&(ROW()-1)`

These work fine on their own, but not when I put them in a VLOOKUP:
`=VLOOKUP("D"&ROW(),D$3:"D$"&(ROW()-1),1,0)`

Using the `ADDRESS` function gave the same error as using the `ROW` function. I have successfully worked around this using `INDIRECT` in the `VLOOKUP` formula, but that seems clunky and unnecessarily complicated. Is there a way to do this without using `INDIRECT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INDIRECT is Volatile; use INDEX instead:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(D:D,ROW()),D$3:INDEX(D:D,ROW()-1),1,FALSE)
```

But upon typing that I see that it would be easier to just put the first row in the reference and keep it dynamic.  So if the first row where 4 then

```
=VLOOKUP(D4,D$3:D3,1,FALSE)
```

Then as it is dragged/copied down only the D4 and the second D3 would change, leaving the first anchored on D3.

Comment: Your index solution worked perfectly, thanks very much for taking the time to help.

Comment: @FrogLegs please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.